# Angular JS material dialog with multiple options to save

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-material

I'm trying to have a dialog with multiple options to save and another option to save and close as well as cancel option, where the (save and close) button will save the data and close the dialog, while the (save) button will save the data in modal then open an empty instance of the modal, the problem is when adding two options with save I see only buttons for save and cancel, here is the angular Material Snippet example I'm modifying:

```
$scope.showConfirm = function(ev) {
    // Appending dialog to document.body to cover sidenav in docs app
    var confirm = $mdDialog.confirm()
          .title('Would you like to delete your debt?')
          .textContent('All of the banks have agreed to forgive you your debts.')
          .ariaLabel('Lucky day')
          .targetEvent(ev)
          .ok('Save and Close')
           .ok('Save')
          .cancel('Cancel');
```

When clicking on Confirm Dialog button I would like to see three buttons, below is the modified code:

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/dgWzjw

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't achieve the dialog presentation you've described using [`$mdDialog.confirm()`](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/api/service/$mdDialog#mddialog-confirm).

This method provides a preconfigured dialog that can only ever have two action buttons. You can build the dialog you want by providing more configuration parameters to [`$mdDialog.show()`](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/api/service/$mdDialog#mddialog-show-optionsorpreset).

Here's an example.

You'll need to provide the HTML for your custom dialog:

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="custom-confirm.html">
  <md-dialog>
    <md-dialog-content>
      <md-content layout-padding>
        <div>...</div>
      </md-content>
    </md-dialog-content>
    <md-dialog-actions>
      <md-button ng-click="cancel()">Cancel</md-button>
      <md-button ng-click="save()">Save</md-button>
      <md-button ng-click="saveAndClose()">Save and Close</md-button>
    </md-dialog-actions>
  </md-dialog>
</script>
```

Then provide a custom dialog configuration to `$mdDialog.show()`:

```
$scope.showCustomConfirm = function () {
  $mdDialog.show({
    controller: function ($scope, $mdDialog) {
      $scope.cancel = function () {
        $mdDialog.cancel();
      };
      $scope.save = function () {
        /* ... */
      };
      $scope.saveAndClose = function () {
        /* ...  */
      };
    },
    templateUrl: 'custom-confirm.html',
  });
};
```

[I've forked your CodePen to include the example described above.](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/bmWvom)

#### Edit

To have the save button reopen the same dialog, simply chain the the call to open the dialog onto a call to first hide it. You can do this because the return value of `$mdDialog.hide()` is a promise that resolves once the dialog has hidden itself.

To follow on from the above example, you'll need to do some some slight refactoring to make sure you're not shadowing `$scope`:

```
$scope.showCustomConfirm = showCustomConfirm;
function showCustomConfirm() {
   $mdDialog.show({
     controller: function ($scope, $mdDialog) {
       $scope.save = function () {
         // Save data...
         $mdDialog.hide().then(showCustomConfirm);
       };
       // Everything else as before...
     },
   });
}
```

[And here's an updated CodePen fork.](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/JmyZBe)

Comment: Thank you for you snippet, how can I modify the save button to save then launch a dialog rather than trigger save function only?so when I press save it will save then open the same dialog

Comment: No problem. I've updated my answer to include an edit which should hopefully address your comment.

Comment: Thanks for the update, now even save and close are triggering the dialog to appear again, what I want to achieve is to have save amd close for saving function and close the dialog, and use the same save function for save button but then launch the empty dialog.

Comment: Ah, right, minor mistake there. All you need to do to fix this is to move whatever you're doing to actually save data out to a separate function, then have both the save and save and close buttons trigger it. Updated fork.

Comment: Thank you for clear description of the problem and solution, marking it as answer

Comment: If I extend this functionality in which I have a form in my mdDialog, it doesn't work, since the button needs to be type=submit not to type=button, so the save and close button works, but adding ng-click for save button only display the modal with outing triggering the saveData function, my code looks like:
`<form ng-submit="saveData($form.validdata)">
      <md-dialog-actions>
        <md-button ng-click="cancel()">Cancel</md-button>
        <md-button ng-click="save()">Save</md-button>
        <md-button>Save and Close</md-button>
      </md-dialog-actions>
</form>`

Comment: Consider posting up another question with relevant snippets of this new form code of yours.

Comment: thank you :) I have opened a question with description and code here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52882446/angular-materialjs-dialog-form-with-different-save-options

Comment: Isn't .then(showCustomConfirm) expecting a resolve and reject parts?

Comment: The return value of [`mdDialog.hide()`](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/api/service/$mdDialog#mddialog-hide-response) is simply a promise that resolves when the dialog has been closed. The `.then()` callback corresponds to the "resolve" part of a Promise. I haven't tested it, but the "reject" part wouldn't make sense anyway for a simple UI hiding operation.