# Angular MaterialJS Dialog form with different save options

Tags: angularjs, forms, angularjs-material, mddialog

I'm trying to save form data in mdDialog but with options of (save and close) the dialog and (save) which will save the form data then open another dialog empty dialog without having to close and open the mdDialog again, the problem is how to call same SaveData function in same form for both save operations?

```
$scope.saveData = function (isValid) {
        if (isValid) {
          updateservice.postdata($scope.myformdata)
            .then(function (data) {
              $mdDialog.hide();
            });
      // error handling
        } 
      };
```

and in the template:

```
<md-dialog>
  <form name="form" ng-submit="saveData(form.$validform)" novalidate>
    <md-dialog-content>
      <div class="md-dialog-content">
        <div>
        </div>
        <table class="table display" border="1" span="1" name="newForm" novalidate role="form" ng-style="{ width: th.width }">
           </tr>
          <tr>
            <td><input type="text" class="form-control text-center" placeholder="required"  ng-required="true"></td>
            <td><input type="text" class="form-control text-center" placeholder="optional" ng-required="true"></td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </div>
    </md-dialog-content>
    <md-dialog-actions layout="row">
      <md-progress-circular md-mode="indeterminate" md-diameter="20px" class="spinner"></md-progress-circular>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="save()" >Save</button> 
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primar">Save and close</button> 
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="cancel()" ng-disabled="loading">Cancel</button>
      </md-dialog-actions>
  </form>
</md-dialog>
```

I changed Save button with type button is not posting the formdata, and changing type to submit like save and close saves data then opens and closes the dialog.

here's codePen with my code:

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZqoYRx

Answer (score 1):

How about passing an argument like isSaveAndClose in the save function:

In HTML:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="save(false)" ng-show="!loading">Save</button> 
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primar" ng-click="save(true)">Save and close</button>
```

In JS:

```
$scope.save = function (isSaveAndClose) {
      saveData();
      if (isSaveAndClose)
        $mdDialog.hide().then(showCustomConfirm);
    };
```

Comment: that didn't solve it, the $mdDialog.show(confirm) gets called but the dialog flashes and closes immediately.
          `this.click = function click (isSaveAndClose) {
            save();
            if (isSaveAndClose) {
              $mdDialog.show(confirm);
            }
          };
        }],
        parent: parentE1, targetEvent: $event,
        controllerAs: 'saveAndclose',
        bindToController: true,
      });
      $mdDialog.show(confirm)
        .then(function () {
        }, function () {
        });
    };`
how to keep the dialog open after save(): is called?

Comment: You mean how to keep the dialog open after "save" not "save and close"?
If you want to keep the dialog open after "save" then just clear the data of the modal after calling saveData(). If you want to completely close the modal after selecting "save and close" then just call $mdDiaglog.hide() without .then(showCustomConfirm).

Comment: Yes that's the goal,how to clear the data after calling saveData();

Comment: If you have input in modal with model say vm.data/$scope.data then call vm.data = null/$scope.data = null after saveData(). Just try it in codePen...

Comment: I have changed my implementation , I want to use one saveData function for both "save" and "save and add", how can I set a condition if it's "save and add" to call ShowNewDialog before resolving with  `$mdDialog.hide();` in the update service? so what changes I need to make in my template to adapt with the implmentation